# How to IP-Forwarding for Man In the Middle Attack

Tags: windows-7, network-programming, router, arp

I`m working on a project about Man In The Middle Attack by ARP poisoning method.

In this project I need to work like as a router. For example suppose In My Lan there is two other device (a modem & a laptop). I says to laptop that I`m the modem to fraud it. whenever the laptop wants to send a packet to outside of the LAN, sends the packet to me!
All thing I need is I want to send the received packet to the modem & sends the response to victim laptop.

How can I do it programmatically?

Thanks a lot.
Ya Ali.

Comment: No one will write a solution for you. Please take a couple of days to try to solve it yourself and then change your question to be more specific.

Comment: I searched couple of days but found nothing. That`s why I posted here to solve my problem advanced users!

Comment: You need to provide some evidence that you tried to develop a solution by showing us what code you've developed so far. You haven't even told us what language you intend to write it in.

Comment: I write nothing because there is nothing. If you search you just find iphlpapi, etc.
Qt or C++ (prefer to Qt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first thing you need to do is perform the ARP poisoning attack. You can review how to do this [in detail here](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/arpspoof).

[image]

One thing of note is that your middle-man PC must how be able to perform like a switch and forward out packets it receives in - It will be passing packets between the modem and the laptop in both directions.

Comment: Yes. I did ARP Spoofing attack & I know my PC must perform kike as a switch. But I dont know how? I need a code or programming algorithm to do it.

Comment: I understand, however you will need to show that you've performed a bit more research and tried it yourself before posting to StackOverflow. No one will write a solution for you. Please take a couple of days to try it yourself and then change your question to be more specific.